# How to submit Xcode "Generic Archive"

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I Archived my app, and usually the "archive type" section says, iOS app, and you can submit directly from organiser. However, the type of this app seems to be "Generic Archive" and asks me to export in 1 of 2 ways When i click on distribute - Save built products - export as Xcode archive.

How do i submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version is you can't. It probably means that your binary has multiple targets inside it. My guess -- as this is what's happened to me -- is that you included an open source project and have it configured incorrectly. Check the "Skip install" setting of any sub-projects.

Comment: I had a static framework and a today extension. I can confirm setting both to Skip Install=YES made it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue of wrong Schemes for multiple targets, check and create new schemes for every target and then go to Build Settings>target dependencies and remove if any!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link this apple document:

http://tinyurl.com/nnxjtzq

Answer (score 0):

When you make archive, It will show at xCode Organizer ,
In

- xCode Organizer find three tab Click on last tab **Archives**
- Select you app and Click on **Distribution**
- There you will find three check box like this image 
  [image]

For submit appstore check first and follow next steps .. 
May be help full for you ...

Comment: This is the usual flow, but when i click on distribute for this type of archive, it asks me to export. and does not allow me to directly submit

Comment: and what about validate button.. It's showing or not ?

Comment: It says cannot be validated

Comment: Then you need to check your provisioning profile for distribution. Please check you provisioning profile , I hope you will get success..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem turns out to be that my cocos2d libraries were included in the build settings. This was solved by

cocos2dLibraries > Build Settings > Skip Install

and making the value "Yes".